# ArrayAdapter's getView() method getting called automatically on load and while scrolling listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

[image]I am creating the custom list activity. There are two classes one is having extended ListActivity and other is having ArrayAdapter for that list activity. This listview contains a textview and a table layout.

Problem is that i am calling getView for eg 2 times its is called automatically thrice, also when i am scrolling the lsitview a row is added automatically.

Please suggest me why this is happening and what should i do to overcome this.

xml for generating custom view

```
displayweek.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               <TableLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               </TableLayout>
      </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

call to getview

```
if (weekAdapter == null) {
            weekAdapter = new weekAdapter(this, 0);
        }
        lvSchedule.setAdapter(weekAdapter);
        weekAdapter.add("true"+","+"10:10Am"+","+"Monday"+","+"Tuesday"+","+"Wednesday"+","+"Thusday"+","+"Friday"
                +","+"Saturday"+","+"Sunday");
        weekAdapter.add("true"+","+"10:10Am"+","+" "+","+" "+","+" "+","+"Sumit"+","+" "+","+" "+","+"Humam");
```

weekAdapter class

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class weekAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    Context context;

    public weekAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.context=context;
    }

    public weekAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context,textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.context=context;
    }



    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
    {

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.displayweek,null);       
        }

        TableLayout table=(TableLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
        TextView tvTime=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);

        String str=getItem(position);
        String []schedule=str.split(",");
        Log.d("schedule length",""+schedule.length);


        if(schedule[0].trim().equals("true"))
            tvTime.setText(""+schedule[1]);
        else
            tvTime.setText("");

         TableRow tr = new TableRow(context);
         tr.setId(1);
         tr.setTag("");                         
         tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         TextView tvMon = new TextView(context);
         tvMon.setId(1);
         tvMon.setText(""+schedule[2]);
         tvMon.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
         tvMon.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         tvMon.setHeight(50);
         tvMon.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
         tr.addView(tvMon);

         TextView tvTue = new TextView(context);
         tvTue.setId(1);
         tvTue.setText(""+schedule[3]);
         tvTue.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
         tvTue.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         tvTue.setHeight(50);
         tvTue.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
         tr.addView(tvTue);

         TextView tvWed = new TextView(context);
         tvWed.setId(1);
         tvWed.setText(""+schedule[4]);
         tvWed.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
         tvWed.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         tvWed.setHeight(50);
         tvWed.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
         tr.addView(tvWed);

         TextView tvThus = new TextView(context);
         tvThus.setId(1);
         tvThus.setText(""+schedule[5]);
         tvThus.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
         tvThus.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         tvThus.setHeight(50);
         tvThus.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
         tr.addView(tvThus);

         TextView tvFri = new TextView(context);
         tvFri.setId(1);
         tvFri.setText(""+schedule[6]);
         tvFri.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
         tvFri.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         tvFri.setHeight(50);
         tvFri.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
         tr.addView(tvFri);

         TextView tvSat = new TextView(context);
         tvSat.setId(1);
         tvSat.setText(""+schedule[7]);
         tvSat.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
         tvSat.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         tvSat.setHeight(50);
         tvSat.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
         tr.addView(tvSat);

         TextView tvSun = new TextView(context);
         tvSun.setId(1);
         tvSun.setText(""+schedule[8]);
         tvSun.setPadding(2, 0, 5, 0);
         tvSun.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         tvSun.setHeight(50);
         tvSun.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
         tr.addView(tvSun);
         table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));             
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: when you scroll listview than getview method call. its a default method you can't change..... and call times it depends on visible item on your screen..

Comment: soo what should i do, to overcome this problem

Comment: This is the functionality of listview to make the the Listview scrolling efficient. I don't know why you don't want this?.

Comment: @Dharmendra you can see i have uploaded an image , an extra row is added, an duplicate display of data is inappropriate by any mean which is my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have not overridden [getCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getCount%28%29) method. This method should return the number of row.

```
public int getCount () {
    return n; /* where n is the number of row you want */
}
```

Besides how do you know the number of rows to be created? Do you need to create it just once for header? In that case you need to inflate that in headerView of List.

getView  getting called is right behavior as the adapter is trying to inflate views at runtime to show in the list.

Comment: No i dont the count for the number of rows, and return 1 displays only 1 item in the row i have added two rows

Comment: You need to return the number of rows you want. So if you want 2 you return 2. If you want n return n.

Comment: value of count is unknown to me, so what should i return

Comment: It has to be known, you need to pass that count in the constructor or how else will the adapter know how many rows to create?

Comment: and getCount doesnot slove my problem

Comment: getcount functions well its display specific number of rows but, while scrolling listview same row is added again at the bottom which is my problem

Comment: dude we are here to not solve your problem but to guide you. Do not expect a complete solution for that would be too expensive for you to afford. Hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Sir, to be honest i don't expect complete solution , what i am trying to convey you is that the solution which you are giving doesn't match my requirement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19365/discussion-between-pravincg-and-hemant)

Comment: This fixed my problem perfectly. Looks like android needs to know how many rows to inflate or else it will only inflate the ones that can be seen on the screen.