# stop getView() from getting called automatically

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, getview

I'm implementing **Expandable ListView**. Each child item has a Text View and an EditText.

The problem is, Suppose a Group has 10 items/rows. I entered a data in row 1 and 2. When I scroll down to row 6 and 7. They already have a text (Row 6 has data of row 1 and Row 7 has data of Row 2).

I understand why this is happeneing.
This is because, When I'm typing in row 1, I can currenlty see row 1 to row 5. When I scroll down to view the remaining rows. **getChildView() is called automatically** to show me remaining rows and thier data, As **all editTexts have same id**. So, Next View has same data as in previous view.
**Similar problem here**: [ArrayAdapter's getView() method getting called automatically on load and while scrolling listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319669/arrayadapters-getview-method-getting-called-automatically-on-load-and-while-s)
**I tried**:

1. his solution, It doesn't work.
2. setting the getChildCount() manually: No Success

Here is my **ExpandableListAdapter.java**:

```
package com.syapaa;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {



    int j=1;
    int neww=0;
    EditText edt;
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;






    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;

    }



    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }



    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        //Don't change://///////////////////////////////-/////////////////////
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        //////////////------------------------------------------------------------/////

        //For Sharing my ID(I am Group PG):
        SharedPreferences prefb = convertView.getContext().getSharedPreferences("my_prefb", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editb = prefb.edit();
        editb.putInt("GR", groupPosition );
        editb.commit();




        if(childPosition==0){
            //Receiving 1857 of OnClick
            SharedPreferences phobjc = convertView.getContext().getSharedPreferences("my_prefd", 0);
            neww = phobjc.getInt("BRNDM", 0);
            phobjc.edit().clear().commit();
        }


        if(neww==1857){
            edt=convertView.findViewById(R.id.marks);
            String abc=edt.getText().toString();


            j=childPosition+1;
            //For Sharing data entered in list:
            SharedPreferences prefa = convertView.getContext().getSharedPreferences("my_prefa", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edita = prefa.edit();
            edita.putString("PH"+j, abc );
            edita.commit();
            Toast.makeText(convertView.getContext(),"Sharing "+ abc+"with "+"PH"+j,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(isLastChild==true){
                int tellmaxitems=childPosition+1;

                //Sharing No of Items in Group
                SharedPreferences prefd = convertView.getContext().getSharedPreferences("noofitems", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editd = prefd.edit();
                editd.putInt("NoItems", tellmaxitems );
                editd.commit();
            }
        }

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;

    }





    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is **Tab1.Java** where I'm adding items in Lists/Rows:

```
package com.syapaa;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;


public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    int grtoShow=0;
    int prGroup=-1;

    String last="ls.txt";
    SwipeRefreshLayout rfrsh;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    Button btn;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);


        // get the listview
        expListView =  v.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);


        //Pull Down to Refresh ListView///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        rfrsh=v.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        rfrsh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                getActivity().finish();
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                startActivity(intent);
                rfrsh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        ////-------Refresh Logic Ends here----------------------------------------/////////////



        ////////Expand Only One Group at a Time (collapse previously Expanded Gruop)///////////////
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int i) {
                new CountDownTimer(120, 1) {
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // When timer is finished
                        // Execute your code here
                        //Taking Group ID (which group was expanded last)
                        SharedPreferences phobjb = getContext().getSharedPreferences("my_prefb", 0);
                        final int i= phobjb.getInt("GR", 0);
                    }
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
                }.start();
                if ((prGroup != -1) && (i != prGroup)) {
                    expListView.collapseGroup(prGroup);
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    try{imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);}
                    catch (Exception e){}
                }
                prGroup = i;
            }
        });
        /////////////-----------Only One Expand at a time Ends here-------------------------/////////////////////

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        //Send Button OnClick Starts /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        btn=v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Sharing Rndom to OnChildView
                SharedPreferences prefd = getContext().getSharedPreferences("my_prefd", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editd = prefd.edit();
                editd.putInt("BRNDM", 1857 );
                editd.commit();

                //Taking Group ID (which group was expanded last)
                SharedPreferences phobjb = getContext().getSharedPreferences("my_prefb", 0);
                int grID = phobjb.getInt("GR", 0);

                expListView.collapseGroup(grID);
                expListView.expandGroup(grID);


                new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // When timer is finished
                        // Execute your code here
                        //Receiving 1857 of OnClick
                        SharedPreferences phobjc = getContext().getSharedPreferences("noofitems", 0);
                        int j = phobjc.getInt("NoItems", 0);
                        phobjc.edit().clear().commit();

                        for(int i=1;i<=j;i++){
                            //Taking data entered in  ETs
                            SharedPreferences phobja = getContext().getSharedPreferences("my_prefa", 0);
                            String data = phobja.getString("PH"+i, "");
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Recving "+data+"from PH"+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        // millisUntilFinished    The amount of time until finished.
                    }
                }.start();



            }
        });
        //-------On Click of button ends here----------------------////////////
        return v;
    }
    //////----------------OnCreate ends here-----------------------------////////////////





    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();


        if(readFile("filePG1.txt").equals(null)||readFile("filePG1.txt").equals("")){
            //pg.add("No Contacts Present");
        }
        else {
            listDataHeader.add("PG");
            List<String> pg = new ArrayList<String>();

            int j=1;
            int i = Integer.parseInt(readFile(last));

            //Start reading from 1 to "How many files are saved"/////////////////
            while (j <= i) {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = getContext().openFileInput("filePG"+ j + ".txt");

                    pg.add(readFile("filePG"+ j + ".txt"));
                    //Add items to listView by reading all saved files/Contacts/////////////

                    int size = fis.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    fis.read(buffer);
                    fis.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //If limit is reached , Break the Loop///////////////////////////
                    break;
                }
                j++;

            }

            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(grtoShow), pg); // Header, Child data
            grtoShow++;


        }


        if(readFile("fileNur1.txt").equals(null)||readFile("fileNur1.txt").equals("")){
            //nur.add("No Contacts Present");
        }
        else {
            listDataHeader.add("Nursery");
            List<String> nur = new ArrayList<String>();

            int j=1;
            int i = Integer.parseInt(readFile(last));

            //Start reading from 1 to "How many files are saved"/////////////////
            while (j <= i) {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = getContext().openFileInput("fileNur"+ j + ".txt");
                    nur.add(readFile("fileNur"+ j + ".txt"));
                    //Add items to listView by reading all saved files/Contacts/////////////

                    int size = fis.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    fis.read(buffer);
                    fis.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //If limit is reached , Break the Loop///////////////////////////
                    break;
                }
                j++;

            }
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(grtoShow), nur);
            grtoShow++;






        }




        if(readFile("filePrep1.txt").equals(null)||readFile("filePrep1.txt").equals("")){
            //prep.add("No Contacts Present");
        }
        else {
            listDataHeader.add("Prep");
            List<String> prep = new ArrayList<String>();
            int j=1;
            int i = Integer.parseInt(readFile(last));

            //Start reading from 1 to "How many files are saved"/////////////////
            while (j <= i) {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = getContext().openFileInput("filePrep"+ j + ".txt");
                    prep.add(readFile("filePrep"+ j + ".txt"));
                    //Add items to listView by reading all saved files/Contacts/////////////

                    int size = fis.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    fis.read(buffer);
                    fis.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //If limit is reached , Break the Loop///////////////////////////
                    break;
                }
                j++;

            }
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(grtoShow), prep);
            grtoShow++;


        }


        if(readFile("fileOne1.txt").equals(null)||readFile("fileOne1.txt").equals("")){
            //one.add("No Contacts Present");
        }
        else {
            listDataHeader.add("One");
            List<String> one = new ArrayList<String>();


            int j=1;
            int i = Integer.parseInt(readFile(last));

            //Start reading from 1 to "How many files are saved"/////////////////
            while (j <= i) {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = getContext().openFileInput("fileOne"+ j + ".txt");
                    one.add(readFile("fileOne"+ j + ".txt"));
                    //Add items to listView by reading all saved files/Contacts/////////////

                    int size = fis.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    fis.read(buffer);
                    fis.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //If limit is reached , Break the Loop///////////////////////////
                    break;
                }
                j++;
            }

            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(grtoShow), one);
            grtoShow++;

        }
        if(readFile("fileTwo1.txt").equals(null)||readFile("fileTwo1.txt").equals("")){
            //two.add("No Contacts Present");
        }
        else {
            listDataHeader.add("Two");
            List<String> two = new ArrayList<String>();

            int j=1;
            int i = Integer.parseInt(readFile(last));

            //Start reading from 1 to "How many files are saved"/////////////////
            while (j <= i) {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = getContext().openFileInput("fileTwo"+ j + ".txt");
                    two.add(readFile("fileTwo"+ j + ".txt"));
                    //Add items to listView by reading all saved files/Contacts/////////////

                    int size = fis.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    fis.read(buffer);
                    fis.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //If limit is reached , Break the Loop///////////////////////////
                    break;
                }
                j++;
            }
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(grtoShow), two);
            grtoShow++;

        }
        if(readFile("fileThree1.txt").equals(null)||readFile("fileThree1.txt").equals("")){
            //three.add("No Contacts Present");
        }
        else {

            listDataHeader.add("Three");
            List<String> three = new ArrayList<String>();

            int j=1;
            int i = Integer.parseInt(readFile(last));

            //Start reading from 1 to "How many files are saved"/////////////////
            while (j <= i) {
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = getContext().openFileInput("fileThree"+ j + ".txt");
                    three.add(readFile("fileThree"+ j + ".txt"));
                    //Add items to listView by reading all saved files/Contacts/////////////

                    int size = fis.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    fis.read(buffer);
                    fis.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //If limit is reached , Break the Loop///////////////////////////
                    break;
                }
                j++;
            }
            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(grtoShow), three);
            grtoShow++;

        }


    }



    public String readFile(String file){
        String text="";
        try {
            FileInputStream fis=getContext().openFileInput(file);
            int size=fis.available();
            byte[] buffer=new byte[size];
            fis.read(buffer);
            fis.close();
            text=new String(buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text;
    }

}
```

So, **How Do I restrict onChildView() to be called only when a group is expanded, Not when View is scrolled/changed.**

Comment: `I understand why this is happeneing. `. Sorry. Dont think so. I dont see you mentioning 'recycling'.

Comment: What's recycling Sir?

Comment: Google for listview items recycling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *getView()* is Android's Own Method, You cannot Override it.
The Only way what you are trying to acheive is:

The Thing you are Trying to do is Certainly Possible, But Complex:

1. Add A Button in Every Child Item
2. When User types in Child 0, He Must Press that Child's Button (on Button Click, Save the value in array on index[childPosition]). In
   this Way, Array[0] will have text of Child 1, Similar for Next
   Children.

(**Step 3 and Further are Optional**)

1. If You Don't like this Design (as User needs to press button every time he enters a value, Refer to Step 4)
2. Set the Visibility of the Button(which was added in Step 1) to *INVISIBLE*
3. Add a TextWatcher (TextChangedListener) for EditText in ChildItem (It will getText entered > Save it in Array[] > Click the Button itself as Soon as User leaves the Current EditText). As:

   ```
   edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

   if(edt.getText().toString()==""&&edt.getText().toString().equals(null)){
   }
   else {
       edt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
               if (!hasFocus)//Perform Click when edt loses Focus {
                   btn.callOnClick();
               }
           }
       });
   }
   }});
   ```

   Now the Button Click will be like:

   ```
   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
           if(edt.getText().toString().equals("")){

           }
           else {
           Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Entered: "+edt.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           myStringArray[childPosition]=edt.getText().toString();
           edt.setText("");
           }
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your view is being recycled, that means Android take the same view that scrolled off the screen, and re-uses it to draw the next one you are scrolling to, since this one you wrote some text into, using the same view will have the same text.

The solution is very simple.

You should have your models reflect the data the user enters in the view. And at any time you should know what text does every child have, maybe use a `TextWatcher`.

And for each child, you simple do the following.

```
String text = getTextForThisChild();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text) {
    yourEditText.setText(text); // Sets correct text for view
} else {
    yourEditText.setText(null); // Clears text of recycled view
}
```

You need to keep track of text changes

```
edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence charSequence, final int i, final int i1, final int i2) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence charSequence, final int i, final int i1, final int i2) {
          yourModelList.get(childPosition).setText(charSequence);  // This is dummy, you should get the correct model for this child
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {}
    });
```

Then in the same model gotten by `yourModelList.get(childPosition)` this is where you get `text` the one you check if is empty or not.

Please let me know if this is still not clear

Comment: Triet adding your code to my getChildView() method.

 Why, Cos It knows what is current child and what text it holds.
So, 
It causes the app to crash when getChildView() is called.
Where do I implement it for proper functioning?

Comment: How do you implement getTextForThisChild in your example?

Comment: `@Override

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        edt=convertView.findViewById(R.id.marks);
        String text = edt.getText().toString();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            edt.setText(text); // Sets correct text for view
        } else {
            edt.setText(null); // Clears text of recycled view
        }
}`
getView already knows what EditText is for this Child. Soi'm just setting the text in this method.

Comment: text = edt.getText() is not correct, you need to save values entered in your views. see edited answer

Comment: Dear, I don't see any answer _edited_. + What could be wrong with: `text = edt.getText()`?

Comment: You talked about saving values currently enetered. But, I don't see any saving algorithm in `TextChangedListener`.
+
`This is dummy, you should get the correct model for this child`
I'm sorry, Explain please. What does this mean?

Comment: Please show the code of the data structure backing this adapter, what is your list/array you are using to populate the list and I can help you populate it

Comment: Check the Updated Question Please and Thanks for Helping :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160232/discussion-between-zubair-younas-and-mahmoud-elmorabea).